# VS2019 unable to debug .net core in WSL2

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, wsl-2

I have VS 2019 community ver 16.9.4.  I've done the following:

- Installed .NET Core Debugging with WSL 2 - 1.0.
- Created a simple hello world C# console app in both .net core 3.1 and 5.0
- Choose WSL2 in debug options and start debug

I'm getting the following error message:

```
One or more errors occurred.

Failed to launch debug adapter. Additional information maybe available in the output window.

The operation was canceled.
```

My output window says:

```
The program '' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

I can confirm that I installed sdk in WSL2 ubuntu 20.04:

```
> dotnet --list-sdks
3.1.408 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
5.0.202 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install `vsdbg` in `WSL`. Run this command in `WSL`.

```
curl -sSL https://aka.ms/getvsdbgsh | /bin/sh /dev/stdin -v latest -l ~/vsdbg
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to reinstall it. I first removed it by executing:

```
rm -r ~/vsdbg
```

and then I install it using @BDisp answer:

```
curl -sSL https://aka.ms/getvsdbgsh | /bin/sh /dev/stdin -v latest -l ~/vsdbg
```

Comment: Thank you, removing it first solved the problem